# Windows display size messed up my website

Tags: css, windows, web-deployment, resolution, display

I keep my laptop display at 125%. And I developed some websites on that. Everything was good until I opened a website on a different laptop which was on 100% display resolution. The website became too small and all layout messed up. I didn't know changing the display to 125% changes every other application too... Most people use on 100% which is also recommended but these websites, I made, are not for 100% resolution. Do I have to change everything now in websites or there is another solution?? Please help me, I'm too much worried about this... I attached sample screenshots of 2 websites...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Jq4.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqmNt.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVz6q.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAc9J.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kulcf.png

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use CSS @media classes to resolve this problem or you can use any framework like bootstrap which has inbuilt classes for all the device size(xs, md, sm, lg, xl).